# Controller action method call have the parameter as NULL while calling javascript in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I use MVC3.
I  have `

```
function userLocation_change()
 {
    var text = $("#userLocation").val();
    alert(text);
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetAllLocations", "Home")';
    var data = text;
    $.post(url, data, function (result) {


        });
}
```

`

Here is my controller action:

```
public JsonResult GetAllLocations(string userlocation)
    {
        ///...some code...
        return Json(..Something.., JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The problem is whenever the controller function is called `"userlocation"` parameter does have a NULL value. I want the `data` value would be passed to the controller action.
Could somebody plz tell me why this happens? Any update would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter to the `@Url.Action` specifically via this overload method for [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470197%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  You can use the [RouteValueDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680272.aspx) inline constructor with to instantiate.

---

Edit: realize now that you need that link to be populated at run time, but the `Url.Action` method generates the link at render time.  I would suggest adding it to the query string and then reading it from the query string in your controller method.  I suspect there is a more elegant way.. but I know this works.

something like: `var url = '@Url.Action("GetAllLocations", "Home")?userlocation=' + $("#userLocation").val();`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your jQuery post function call as:

```
$.post(  
    url,  
    { userlocation: text },  
    function(result){
       ....
});
```

This is because, you have to send data to the Controller's action method using JavaScript literal. You can view the full listing of different ways to call Controller's action using JavaScript here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_posting_to.ashx

Answer (score 0):

Your action has a string input parameter named `userlocation`, hence while sending the data to the action, you should specify this, like done in the code below.

Here I am using `data: { userlocation: text},`

```
function userLocation_change()
 {
    var text = $("#userLocation").val();
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetAllLocations", "Home")';

    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { userlocation: text},     
    success: function (result) {

    }
    });
}
```

Hopes this solves your null problem.